# Writing a shell script to loop and print out numbers 0-100 and if they are even or odd

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a script to do as the question title says but I'm getting an error and I can not understand why. I'm quite new to bash and shell scripting so any help is appreciated.
here is my code:

```
for i in {0..100}
do
if [ $i % 2 = 0  ]
        echo "Number: $i and is even."
else
        echo "Number: $i and is odd."
fi
done
```

Comment: Use https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `then` after `if`. Also your test expression in `if` is incorrect

```sh
for i in {0..100}
do
if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 0  ]
then
        echo "Number: $i and is even."
else
        echo "Number: $i and is odd."
fi
done
```

`$(($i % 2))` is for [Arithmetic-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

Comment: This works thank you! I will mark as the answer when I can